# declaring global struct pointer in c++ for linked list in unix (putty)

Tags: pointers, linked-list, global-variables

I'm trying to create a linked list data structure for a mobile store database. I'm facing problems in declaring a global pointer for struct mobile. In the method view_all(), im not able to get the output of the entered variables.

I'm executing this code as mobile.cpp with the help of putty in unix operating system.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct mobile
{
                char make[15];
                char model[10];
                float price;
                mobile *link;
}*start;

void add_new ()
{
        struct mobile *temp, *traverse;
        temp = new struct mobile;
        traverse = start;
        if (start==NULL)
        {
             temp=start;
        }
        else
     { 
        while (traverse->link!=NULL)
        {
                traverse=traverse->link;
        }
        traverse->link=temp;
      }

        temp->make="BlackBerry";
        temp->model="BB9320";
        temp->price=12000;
}

void view_all ()
{

        struct mobile *temp;
        temp = new struct mobile;
        temp=start;
        cout <<"Mobile make:"<<temp->make;
        cout <<"Mobile price:"<<temp->price;
}




int main ()
{
        add_new ();
        view_all ();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: in general it makes sense to create a minimal example code of your problem. this way helpers have to waste less time, and people with the same problem can more easily see that it is the same problem.

Comment: sorry i thought it would be better if i paste the entire code as it is. anyway i've made it short to the essential part.
the error im getting is stagnancy error: core dumped

Comment: what compiler and version are you using? i suspect it is a very old one, cause on my linux system, using g++ 4.8.2, i get multiple compilation errors (which would help you a lot already). you should probably also initialize the start pointer (*start = NULL;)

Comment: i did. its giving segmentation fault.

Comment: what compiler and version are you using?

Comment: i'm using it in unix through putty.
i also tried dev cpp and online editor : http://cpp.sh/

Comment: i need name of the compiler, and version. unix has many compilers, and endless amount of versions.

Comment: for example, if you use gcc, you can find out the version with `g++ --version`. also, you could try executing in a debugger (for example GDB)